# Google Sheets: sort two column based on another column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column, we'll call it Index1, in my Google Sheet.

I have two other columns that I've copy pasted into the same sheet, one that has the same numbers Index1, but is not sorted in the same order as the original Index1 column. We'll call it Index2. Then there's a Value column that corresponds to the Index2 column.

I want to rearrange the Index2|Value pairings such that Index1 matches with Index2. So at the end of it, I'll have Index1 and Index2 right next to each other with identical values, and the corresponding Value column right next to that. Is there a good way to do that in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Vlookup:D1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A:A,B:C,2,0))
```

- A:Index1
- B:Index2
- C:Value of Index2
- D:Value of Index1